# Evaluating residua and simplifying complex expressions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

My question is in two parts, so please forgive its long-winded nature.

Lets say that I want to find the residua of the following complex function:

$$f(w)=\frac{2w+1}{w(w^3-5)}$$

Let us, furthermore, only consider finding the residua of the function that correspond to the "second" part of the denominator. That is, the residua at the poles,

$$w^3=5$$

We see that here our three poles will be of the form,

$$w=5^{\frac 13}(\cos(2n+1)\pi+i\sin(2n+1)\pi)$$

For $n=1,2,3$

Now, here we have three simple poles, and I am wondering if what I have done here is correct in trying to evaluate the residua.

First of all, let

$$A:=5^{\frac 13}(\cos(2n+1)\pi+i\sin(2n+1)\pi)$$

Then,

$$Res_{w=A}f(w)=\lim_{w\to A}\{(w-A)\frac{(2w+1)}{w(w^3-5)}\}\tag{$\ast$}$$

**Here comes the first point of the question**; are we able to manipulate $(w^3-5)$ into such a form equivalent to $(w-A)$ so that they might cancel? Here is what I have done:

$$(w^3-5)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow w^3=5$$

$$\Rightarrow w=A$$

$$\Rightarrow w-A=0$$

$$\iff (w^3-5)=(w-A)$$

Which would mean that we could rewrite $(\ast)$ as

$$Res_{w=A}f(w)=\lim_{w\to A}\{(w-A)\frac{(2w+1)}{w(w-A)}\}$$

Thus allowing us to evaluate the residue simply as,

$$Res_{w=A}f(w)=\lim_{w\to A}\{\frac{(2w+1)}{w}\}$$

Have I done this correctly? Is this the right way to go about this occurence for such a type of problem?

**The second point of my question is this**, evaluating the limit leaves me with the following expression;

$$\lim_{w\to A}\{\frac{(2w+1)}{w}\}=2+\frac1{5^{\frac 13}(\cos(2n+1)\pi+i\sin(2n+1)\pi)}$$

Is there any way to *formally* tidy this up without having to resort to setting $A:=5^{\frac 13}(\cos(2n+1)\pi+i\sin(2n+1)\pi)$?

Comment: I don't recall hearing *residues* called *residua*.  Where does that come from?

Comment: I got it from how my teacher calls the plural form of residue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* The following should answer both parts of your question.

> We observe the function
>   \begin{align*}
>   f(w)=\frac{2w+1}{w(w^3-5)}
>   \end{align*}
>   has four simple poles, one at $w=0$ and $w_0,w_1,w_2$ with
>   $$w_j^3=5\qquad\qquad j=0,1,2$$

We consider the *roots of unity* to the power three:

$$e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{3}}=\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi i}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi i}{3}\right)\qquad\qquad k=0,1,2$$

The poles $w_o,w_1,w_2$ can therefore be written as $\sqrt[3]{5}$ times these roots of unity and we obtain
\begin{align*}
  w_0&=\sqrt[3]{5}\\
  w_1&=\sqrt[3]{5}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{5}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)\\
  w_2&=\sqrt[3]{5}e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{5}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)\\
  \end{align*}

> Let's calculate the residue of $f$ at $w=w_0=\sqrt[3]{5}$
>
> Since $w_0$ is a simple pole of $f$ we can calculate it via
>
> \begin{align*}
>   Res_{w=w_0}f(w)&=\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}\left((w-w_0)\frac{2w+1}{w(w^3-5)}\right)\\
>   &=\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}\left((w-w_0)\frac{2w+1}{w(w-w_0)(w-w_1)(w-w_2)}\right)\\
>   &=\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}\frac{2w+1}{w(w-w_1)(w-w_2)}\tag{1}\\
>   &=\frac{2w_0+1}{w_0(w_0-w_1)(w_0-w_2)}\\
>   &=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{5}+1}
>   {\sqrt[3]{5}\left(\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{5}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{5}e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\right)}\\
>    &=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{5}+1}
>   {5\left(1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)\left(1-e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{5}+1}
>       {5\left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)\right)
>         \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)\right)}\\
>  &=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{5}+1}{5\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)
>         \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{5}+1}{5\left(\frac{9}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{15}\left(2\sqrt[3]{5}+1\right)\\
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:* In (1) we have cancelled the factor $w-w_0$. But with respect to the first part of your question please note, we have to keep the other factors of $w^3-5$. Regarding the second part of your question you might find the following approach convenient.

Similarly we could calculate the residues at the other simple poles. But, we can do it considerably simpler.

> Let's calculate the residue of $f$ at the simple pole $w=w_0$ once again.
>
> Observe, the function $f$ can be written in the form
>   $$f(w)=\frac{P(w)}{Q(w)}$$
>   with $P(w)$ analytic in a neighborhood of $w_0$ and $Q(w)$ having a simple zero at $w_0$. We can write
>   \begin{align*}
>   Res_{w=w_0}f(w)&=\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}(w-w_0)f(w)\\
>   &=\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}(w-w_0)\frac{P(w)}{Q(w)}\\
>   &=\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}\frac{P(w)}{\frac{Q(w)-Q(w_0)}{w-w_0}}\\
>   \end{align*}
>   Note, that $Q(w_0)=0$.
>
> It follows
>   \begin{align*}
>   Res_{w=w_0}f(w)&=\frac{P(w_0)}{Q^{\prime}(w_0)}\\
>   \end{align*}

This makes calculation considerably easier.

> Since $$f(w)=\frac{2w+1}{w(w^3-5)}=\frac{2w+1}{w^4-5w}$$ we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
>   Res_{w=w_0}f(w)&=\frac{P(w_0)}{Q^{\prime}(w_0)}\\
>     &=\left.\frac{2w+1}{\left(w^4-5w\right)^{\prime}}\right|_{w=w_0}\\
>     &=\left.\frac{2w+1}{4w^3-5}\right|_{w=w_0}\\
>     &=\frac{2w_0+1}{4w_0^3-5}\\
>     &=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{5}+1}{4\cdot 5-5}\\
>     &=\frac{1}{15}\left(2\sqrt[3]{5}+1\right)\\
>   \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all of this, it makes a lot more sense now. Thanks again!

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames: You're welcome! :-)